# I have a icon within the button , I want that when user click that icon the button disapper in other words it shoulb not be visible anymore

Tags: reactjs, icons, material-design, react-hooks

I am using close icon within the button, and for that, I want that when user click on the icon within the button the button eventually disappear from the frontend

how could I do this, this is the sample code

[this is sample code](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-7t93l)

Thanks

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. You need to post the relevant code in the question itself.

Comment: my bad dave will keep in mind for next time !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
export default function IconLabelButtons() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(true);

  function handleClickOpen() {
    setOpen(true);
  }

  function handleClose() {
    setOpen(false);
  }
  const renderDisplayStyle = open ? 'block' : 'none'

  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="secondary"
        className={classes.button}
        style={{ display: renderDisplayStyle  }}
      >
        Delete
        <DeleteIcon className={classes.rightIcon} onClick={handleClose} />
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

or

```
  export default function IconLabelButtons() {
      const classes = useStyles();
      const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(true);

      function handleClickOpen() {
        setOpen(true);
      }

      function handleClose() {
        setOpen(false);
      }

      return (
        <div>
          {
             open &&
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            color="secondary"
            className={classes.button}
          >
            Delete
            <DeleteIcon className={classes.rightIcon} onClick={handleClose} />
          </Button>
        }
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Comment: what if I have multiple buttons but only want to close selected one ???

Comment: @Bilawal Then you need to maintain visibility state for each button.

Answer (score 1):

Search for "react conditional rendering" (or read about it [in the React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html); it's a basic React concept with multiple implementions.

You currently have the click handler on the icon, not on the button–while this *may* be what you want, it's an unexpected UX in that normally people expect buttons to be clickable, not a specific element in the button.

Then use normal conditional rendering to display or hide the button (with the caveat that if you're doing this in other places you may want to extract this out into a component).

Also, depending on your actual needs, it may be better to render it as disabled rather than completely removing the button.

```
  return (
    <div>
      {open && (
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="secondary"
          className={classes.button}
          onClick={handleClose}
        >
          Delete
          <DeleteIcon className={classes.rightIcon} />
        </Button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-t0d3n

Answer (score 1):

You can make like this;

```
<div style={{ 'display': open ? 'block' : 'none' }}>
  <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" className={classes.button}>
    Delete
    <DeleteIcon className={classes.rightIcon} onClick={handleClose} />
  </Button>
</div>
```